# IIS Hosted Application not working when called using IP address

Tags: .net, silverlight, http, iis, networking

i have hosted Silverlight application in IIS. it works fine using local host and using my IP address in my Machine but when i use the same URL in Lan Connected system it doest work .
pls help me with this

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting the IIS Instance on your local machine and are unable to access it from another computer then its most likely your local firewall blocking the connection.

You will need to allow port 80 and 443 (assuming you haven't changed these in IIS)

The URL  you use from the other computer needs to be the IP address or your machine as well. If you are using a domain name and it is not configured to your local IP address through host files then you will not be able to access it either.